# Python-filtering list of objects

Tags: python

I have created a class as below and have created data list which holds object of this class.

```
class  flight:  
    origin = ""
    dest = ""
    depdelay = 0
    arrdelay = 0
    dist = 0
```

I am trying to make groups and filtering based on certain criteria as below-

```
x=0
grouping = []
for i in range (0,12):

  group = filter(lambda s:s.dist >=(x+1) and s.dist <= (x+200),data)
  total2 = len(list(group))
  print(total2)
  subgroup = filter(lambda r:r.arrdelay == 0,group)
  subgroup = filter(lambda r:r.depdelay == 0,subgroup)
  subgroup = list(subgroup)
  print(len(subgroup))
  ontimegroup = len(subgroup)/total2
  grouping.append(ontimegroup)
  x=x+200
```

on doing this I am able to filter data in group but after that i get a blank list.My data has arrdelay ==0 and depdelay ==0.

Not sure what is wrong here and why i am getting a null list in subgroup.

Comment: Did you define your class that way? Because now `origin`, etc. are **class** attributes...

Comment: You have `flight.dist = 0` however in the first line of your `for` loop you're `filter`ing for `s.dist >= 1 and s.dist <= 200` which is probably not fulfilled for any point in `data`.

Comment: If your class doesn't need methods, you might as well use a `dict`. Or `collections.namedtuple` for slightly easier attribute access.

Comment: I tried running your code and got `NameError: name 'data' is not defined`. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I appreciate the help.. I think I should have provided the data I am passing and be more clear about it. I was able to debug it. The problem was that I was not making it a list before filtering it again..